# How to disable the selected option from other select list in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-select

I am setting up a select list From Year and To Year through ng-repeat and its working fine what I need is when I select an option from the list it should be disabled from another list. how to do using Angularjs?

Thank You.

HTML

```
<li> 
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected disabled>From Year</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in selectedYear" >{{option.years}}</option>
    </select>
</li>

<li>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected disabled>To Year</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in selectedYear" >{{option.years}}</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

JSON

```
{"json1":"[{\"years\":2018},{\"years\":2017},{\"years\":2016},{\"years\":2015}]
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you can post code using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: had you tried anything?

Comment: yeah, I tried previous answers but I couldn't achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following snippet and let me know, is this what exactly you want

```js
angular.module("app", [])

  .run(($rootScope) => {

    $rootScope.selectedYears = []

    $rootScope.years = [{
      "years": 2018
    }, {
      "years": 2017
    }, {
      "years": 2016
    }, {
      "years": 2015
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <li>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedYears[0]">
      <option value="" selected disabled>From Year</option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in years"
              ng-disabled="selectedYears.indexOf(option.years) !== -1 && selectedYears.indexOf(option.years) !== 0"
              ng-value="{{option.years}}">
        {{option.years}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model=selectedYears[1]>
      <option value="" selected disabled>To Year</option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in years"
              ng-disabled="selectedYears.indexOf(option.years) !== -1 && selectedYears.indexOf(option.years) !== 1"
              ng-value="{{option.years}}">
        {{option.years}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </li>
</div>
```